# sbt play framework exception: java.io.IOException: org.scalasbt.ipcsocket.NativeErrorException: [1] Operation not permitted

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

In a java project play framework 2.8.8 with sbt 1.5.2 when I run sbt command to execute the program i receive this alert/question:

```
java.io.IOException: org.scalasbt.ipcsocket.NativeErrorException: [1] Operation not permitted
Create a new server? y/n (default y)
```

The application is running in a virtualbox shared folder unix/windows. I know that problem depends on my shared folder. I have tried to use command  `-Dsbt.server.forcestart=true` without any success. Otherwise I cannot use another folder to run my project.
Exist a way to solve it and avoid the confirmation after sbt java io exception?

thanks